I need help with min problem
Set Warnings "-notation-overridden,-parsing,-deprecated-hint-without-locality".
Set Warnings "-intuition-auto-with-star".
From Coq Require Import Strings.String.
From PLF Require Import Maps.
From Coq Require Import Bool.Bool.
From Coq Require Import Arith.Arith.
From Coq Require Import Arith.EqNat.
From Coq Require Import Arith.PeanoNat. Import Nat.
From Coq Require Import Lia.
From PLF Require Export Imp.
From PLF Require Import Hoare.
From PLF Require Import Hoare2.
Set Default Goal Selector "!".

Open Scope dcom_scope.

(* ================================================================= *)
(** ** Exercise: Minimum *)

Definition minimum (a b : nat) : decorated := 
<{ {{ True }} ->>
   {{ min a b + 0 = min a b }}
    X := a
      {{ap2 min X b + 0 = min a b }};
    Y := b
      {{ ap2 min X Y + 0 = min a b }};
    Z := 0
      {{ ap2 min X Y + Z = min a b }};
    while X <> 0 && Y <> 0 do
      {{ Z + ap2 min X Y = min a b /\ X * Y <> 0 }} ->>
      {{ Z + 1 + ap2 min (X-1) (Y-1) = min a b }}
      X := X - 1
        {{ Z + 1 + ap2 min X (Y-1) = min a b }};
      Y := Y - 1
        {{ Z + 1 + ap2 min X Y = min a b }};
      Z := Z + 1
        {{ Z + ap2 min X Y = min a b }}
    end
  {{ Z + ap2 min X Y = min a b /\ (X = 0 \/ Y = 0) }} ->>
  {{ Z = min a b }}
}>.

this is what i have come up till now.
Theorem minimum_correct : forall a b,
  outer_triple_valid (minimum a b).
Proof.
  verify.
  - apply andb_true_iff in H0.
    destruct H0 as [HX HY].
    apply negb_true_iff in HX.
    apply negb_true_iff in HY.
    apply eqb_neq in HX.
    apply eqb_neq in HY.
    destruct (st X) eqn:Ex, (st Y) eqn:Ey; try lia;
    rewrite Nat.mul_eq_0; intuition.
  - apply andb_false_iff in H0.
    destruct H0 as [H0|H0];
    apply negb_false_iff in H0;
    apply eqb_eq in H0;
    auto.
Qed.

As shown i have completed the defination and proved the goals i was facing when using tactic "verify". My only question now is there a way to make my defination in such a way that i get no goals when using tactic "verify". I am asking this question because there are some cases this is possible. If anyone knows and can help me please do.
Edit:
adding 2 links as suggested.
https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/index.html
https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/Hoare2.html#lab119
the following image shows the goals i get. They are proved as well. Is there a way to make my loop invariant better so that i can get maybe 2 goals.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/KPZC1cYG.png

Please explain which proof assistant you are talking about, and use the code block (triple ``` and ''') to properly display the code. The question is not readable. Also the code should compile, or else we cannot try to do what you are trying to do.

@AndrejBauer I have edited the question. Sorry it was my first time asking question.

Thanks. This is not valid Coq syntax, you must be using some libraries. Please make sure to have a working definition.

In particular, please include your Import statements!

I have added the imports. But certain imports require files from this book which you need to download https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/index.html. We have to use two files Hoare and Hoare2 from this.

Prerequisites (it is not as simple as you put it): https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/Equiv.html#lab10

The exercise in question: https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/Hoare2.html#lab119

added the links for more clarification. and as you suggested it is as an excercise in book but there is no solution available. I have managed to solve it but there are some goals which i am not able to incorporate in defination. Hence looking for help :(.

This site is not for solving your homework, or providing solutions to exercises which have (on purpose) no publicly accessible solutions. We can help you understand things if you are stuck at a particular point, or confused by a particular mechanism. But for this you will need to tell us more: what are the goals you get? Why don't you understand them?

@MevenLennon-Bertrand I have done the proof and let me update this question.

It seems your proof does not apply to the annotated program you gave us. Is it possible you changed the annotations to do the proof but did not reflect it here?

@MevenLennon-Bertrand It is working for me. I can paste screenshots if required

I'm pretty sure the first non-trivial Hoare triple is not {{ X = a /\  Y = b }}.

@MevenLennon-Bertrand I have updated the code i made some changes to optimise it. Can you let me know if there is an issue with this one

The tactic verify does basically two things. First, it applies the verification_correct lemma, which show that the Hoare triple for the whole program follows from the logical rules for each program instruction. That is, it generates a long list of "local" conditions which, when they are all proven, imply the "global" property of the function.
Second, and more interestingly, it calls the verify_assertion tactic. To quote PLF, this tactic

will help with proving assertions throughout the rest of this chapter. You don't need to understand the details, but briefly: it uses [split] repeatedly to turn all the conjunctions into separate subgoals, tries to use several theorems about booleans and (in)equalities, then uses eauto and lia to finish off as many subgoals as possible. What's left after verify_assertion does its thing should be just the "interesting parts" of the proof – which, if we're lucky, might be nothing at all!

And indeed, in simple cases earlier in the book verify_assertion is good enough to automatically handle all goals generated by verification_correct.
The issue you are facing does not really come from your invariants. Rather, it is an issue with verify_assertion not being "smart enough" to solve your goals automatically. Crucially, it does not know how to translate the boolean operations && and || into the logical /\ and \/, which is necessary to decompose the logical condition of the while loop.
If you wanted to correct this, I would suggest enhancing verify_assertion. For instance, you could give a "logical" version of beval, ie a function bevalp valued in Prop rather than bool, show that bassertion b st <-> bevalp st b, and use that to cleanly transform all boolean conditionals to propositional connectives which eauto and lia can more easily use.

Yes, i asked with a few people on what verify is doing for them and it is the way you explained it minimizes as much possible and then we need to prove goals in theorm.
